# Galaxy tab 2 doesn't recognize Canon EOS Rebel T2i

Tags: canon, android

I wanted to connect my EOS Rebel T2i to a Galaxy tab 2 so I can controll it with DSLR controller app, yet it doesn't work. At first I thought, that it could be an issue with the app, but then I realised, that not only the app, but even the device does't see anything connected on USB when I plug my camera.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply connect devices to most Android phones or tablets with a standard cable. You need a [USB OTG ('On the Go')](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable instead.